# Is there a way to run non-void python functions periodically?

Tags: python

I have a code snippet that I would like to execute periodically every 30 seconds. I'm using time.sleep() at the moment which is bad because it blocks any interaction with the program for the meantime but i didn't find any other way to do it. The code is:

```
while True:
    mapMatrix=updateMaps(mapMatrix,5,before)
    allPlayersRecommendation(initiallyPlayed, arrayPlayerStats, mapMatrix)
    time.sleep(30)
```

I've found multiple ways to run **void functions** periodically with the threading library but this one is different because I need to store a value in the variable `mapMatrix`.

Comment: This could be solved using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: Is `while True` your game loop? You don't need threads. Or async. Just add a condition: `if 30 seconds passed: updateMapMatrix()`. Threads and async are needless complications which should be avoided unless you really need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not such a problem as you may think that threading makes a general assumption of a **void** task, what it seems you are trying to accomplish here is assigning a result of a function to a variable.  Since the "result" of a thread's `target` function is discarded, this poses a problem.

Our solution is quite simple though, you can simply wrap the variable assignment inside a void function

```
import threading
import time

a = 0


def get_result():
    return time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")

def routine():
    global a
    while True:
        a = get_result()
        time.sleep(5)

threading.Thread(target=routine).start()

while True:
    print(a)
```

The thread directly runs `routine`, which will run `get_result` on an interval and store that result into the global variable `a`.

You should still, however, consider the advice from commenters that `threading` may not be the most appropriate solution here. Still, the assumption that threads cannot accomplish this task easily in python is false.

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks a lot! I'll remember this